# Typo3: classes for elements

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have 3 different kinds of  in my website, and I want to give be able to give different classes from the backend using the RTE from the Text Element. It should look like this:

```
<ul class="type2">
  ....
</ul`>
```

I thought I should use one of the 3 boxes from the RTE, probably "blockstyle", but im not sure how to add new options to this dropdow. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standard RTE editor (rtehtmlarea) populates the class list by parsing the CSS file that you set for it so all you need to do is to define `ul.type2` in that CSS file. See the manual of the extension and search for `contentCSS` property. Example:

```
RTE.default.contentCSS = fileadmin/template/rte.css
```

Note that you might have to set it also for each table, e.g.:

```
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.contentCSS = fileadmin/template/rte.css
```

This depends on your configuration and whether you already have default settings (`RTE.default`) copied into other configurations. See **Info -> [page] -> Page TSconfig -> RTE.** for your current settings.